# encrypt/decrypt text input by user and save as variable to use later

Tags: windows, batch-file

i found this code for direct replacement of text input with some other characters u define as simple encryption/decryption method code was modified by @Aacini
the problem is when i try to encode some directories like
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe"
it'll result in this

```
7EzkSw]8Z8KFSBheZL4HXWPj5mZda7tFXveyJHXWPj5qFYBS6qYAnsbZFXRRgWua5CW65QMWuezmzLx6ry4ReEfnPAxZFXRRgv275kQHhRN7HvvpYPWAd2Kj88Z8KFSqFYBS6NF7SQUmZda7tYrGxPa6ry4Re
```

problem is it'll never encode the colon :
how ever if i manually entered the colon code defined in the data which is : = xU9pbp for decryption it'll decrypt the colon value
problem only with encryption will result in ] as in value up `7EzkSw]`

### and decryption always stop at 1st letter which is  `C`

code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Encrypt and decrypt string
color a

rem Create Encrypt/Decrypt arrays
set "charSet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890@#$*(.,- \/:"
set i=0
for %%a in (
    qFYBS6  YrGxPa  7EzkSw  NF7SQU  6ry4Re
    Wua5CW  FXveyJ  TjMmgD  65QMWu  GkmBEE
    KXNe9s  ezmzLx  qYAnsb  dd4PWp  mZda7t
    BheZL4  WUmv8U  HXWPj5  EfnPAx  kBEypV
    tDNJde  zxNvTT  YJ5Pms  HhRN7H  Vkh3EX
    4WfDP3  EQUgc5  abYL93  EBLCJa  xEgKbW
    Z6QA9U  Ad2Kj8  zRDwx9  vvpYPW  ms499B
    55FGHB  eu3RA9  FSYKz9  KsTuqW  ETjRHF
    v275kQ  KUngv8  2Z9ba8  Xtxkzp  ZFXRRg
    8Z8KFS  a2yjt4  xU9pbp) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!charSet:~%%i,1!") do (
      set "ENC[%%c]=%%a"
      set "DEC[%%a]=%%c"
   )
   set /A i+=1
)

echo Enter a string to encrypt:
set /p Encrypt=
REM cls
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt%
set "EncryptOut="
:encrypt2
set "EncryptOut=%EncryptOut%!ENC[%Encrypt2:~0,1%]!"
set "Encrypt2=%Encrypt2:~1%"
if defined Encrypt2 goto encrypt2
echo %EncryptOut%>>"encrypted.txt"
echo/
set /p CryptedPass=< "encrypted.txt"
echo Input string clear text ===^> %Encrypt%
echo/
echo Output string crypted   ===^> %CryptedPass%
pause

set /p Decrypt=<"encrypted.txt"
REM cls
ECHO/
ECHO/
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt%
set "DecryptOut="
:decrypt2
set "DecryptOut=%DecryptOut%!DEC[%Decrypt2:~0,6%]!"
set "Decrypt2=%Decrypt2:~6%"
if defined Decrypt2 goto decrypt2
echo Input string: %Decrypt%
echo/
echo Output string: %DecryptOut%
pause
```

Comment: Also, you always decrypt the same string, because you *append* to a file (`echo %EncryptOut%>>"encrypted.txt"`), but always read the *first* line (`set /p CryptedPass=< "encrypted.txt"`). Change `>>` to `>`: `echo %EncryptOut%>"encrypted.txt"`

Comment: the code i'll use meant to only use one string by user and safe it encrypted in a file so user doesn't play with it but the issue is the colon : in the text he enters it won't get replaced and i don't know much about cmd to play with its variables and constants and edit them

Answer (score 0):

i came around the issue with attempt to replace ] in the output to the colon value and then save it and it was a success as when decode again the path comes back to original with the colon : i it